# CouchDB views - Multiple join... Can it be done?

Tags: couchdb

I have three document types MainCategory, Category, SubCategory... each have a parentid which relates to the id of their parent document.

So I want to set up a view so that I can get a list of SubCategories which sit under the MainCategory (preferably just using a map function)... I haven't found a way to arrange the view so this is possible.

I currently have set up a view which gets the following output -

```
    {"total_rows":16,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"11098","key":["22056",0,"11098"],"value":"MainCat...."},
{"id":"11098","key":["22056",1,"11098"],"value":"Cat...."},
{"id":"33610","key":["22056",2,"null"],"value":"SubCat...."},
{"id":"33989","key":["22056",2,"null"],"value":"SubCat...."},
{"id":"11810","key":["22245",0,"11810"],"value":"MainCat...."},
{"id":"11810","key":["22245",1,"11810"],"value":"Cat...."},
{"id":"33106","key":["22245",2,"null"],"value":"SubCat...."},
{"id":"33321","key":["22245",2,"null"],"value":"SubCat...."},
{"id":"11098","key":["22479",0,"11098"],"value":"MainCat...."},
{"id":"11098","key":["22479",1,"11098"],"value":"Cat...."},
{"id":"11810","key":["22945",0,"11810"],"value":"MainCat...."},
{"id":"11810","key":["22945",1,"11810"],"value":"Cat...."},
{"id":"33123","key":["22945",2,"null"],"value":"SubCat...."},
{"id":"33453","key":["22945",2,"null"],"value":"SubCat...."},
{"id":"33667","key":["22945",2,"null"],"value":"SubCat...."},
{"id":"33987","key":["22945",2,"null"],"value":"SubCat...."}
]}
```

Which QueryString parameters would I use to get say the rows which have a key that starts with ["22945".... When all I have (at query time) is the id "11810" (at query time I don't have knowledge of the id "22945").

If any of that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you store your categories seems to be suboptimal for the query you try to perform on it.

MongoDB.org has a page on [various strategies to implement tree-structures](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB) (they should apply to Couch and other doc dbs as well) - you should consider `Array of Ancestors`, where you always store the full path to your node. This makes updating/moving categories more difficult, but querying is easy and fast.

Comment: Marcel Thanks for your input. I have taken your advice and gone with the "Array of Ancestors"... It works really well.

Comment: I have also created a list function to spit out the flat views into a tree structure which also works well.